# show the following $ |\int_0^a{2x+2\ln(1+x)}dx-2a^2+\frac{a^3}{3}-\frac{a^4}{6}|\leq \frac{1}{10}a^5 $

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion, solution-verification

Can someone check if my answer is correct because I'm not sure if I have done it right? I think I have, but I'm not sure :)

Thanks in advance

---

Consider the function $f(x)=2x+2\ln(1+x)$ for $x>-1$ and centered at $0$.

Show that
$$|f(x)-T_3(x)|\leq\frac{x^4}{2}$$
for all $x\geq0$. Where $T_3(x)=4x-x^2+\frac{2}{3}x^3$

Use it to show the following
$$
|\int_0^a{2x+2\ln(1+x)}dx-2a^2+\frac{a^3}{3}-\frac{a^4}{6}|\leq \frac{1}{10}a^5
$$

### Answer:

To show the first inequality
$$|f(x)-T_3(x)|\leq\frac{x^4}{2}$$
I use the The Remainder Estimation Theorem:
$$|f(x)-T_n(x)| \leq \frac{M_n}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$$
Where $n=3$
$$|f^{(3+1)}(x)| \leq M_3$$
$$|f^{(4)}(x)|=\frac{12}{(x+1)^4}$$
And for all $x \geq 0$, we have that
$$M_3=12$$
So we have
$$|f(x)-T_3(x)| \leq \frac{12}{4!}x^{4}=\frac{12}{24}x^{4}=\frac{1}{2}x^{4}$$

And to show the last inequality where
$$\int_0^a{T_3(x)}dx=2a^2-\frac{a^3}{3}+\frac{a^4}{6}$$ is an approximation of the integral
$$\int_0^a{2x+2\ln(1+x)}dx$$
so we have that
$$
|\int_0^a{2x+2\ln(1+x)}dx-2a^2+\frac{a^3}{3}-\frac{a^4}{6}|\leq \int_0^a{\frac{x^4}{2}}dx=[\frac{x^5}{10}]_0^a=\frac{a^5}{10}-\frac{0^5}{10}=\frac{a^5}{10}
$$
We have now shown the last inequality